How to replacing remote notification's mobile phone with contact name in device react native?
I have a remote notification from backend with format {title: App Name, body:"[$phone] changed something on the app"}. We use firebase cloud messaging for push notification from backend. And I need to modified this notification replacing phone with user's contact name in react native before display to user in background or exit state. How can I achieve this ? Very thankful for the helping.

Firebase Cloud Messaging supports two types of messages:


Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
Data messages, which are handled by the client app.


Most likely you are currently sending a notification message, which is handled by the system (unless the user is actively using the app).
If you always want your application code to handle and display the message, you should send a data-only message.

Thanks a lot. Just 1 more question. So if a notification is coming. I had to catch with setBackgroundMessageHandler and use some library to push notification with data return, am i right ? i use this library for setBackgroundMessageHandler https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage
